# Proper methodology in adding additional info to a PostgreSQL database (seeds.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Conceptually, I understand what seeds.rb represents. It's a means to hold a script that handles the logic of populating a database before the application should be run.

However, from what I can tell, it's not really possible to "update" seeds.rb. It's only meant for the absolute base data required for the application, so if it needs to be updated, you'd have to clear our the database entirely before running the seed command.

This leads me to the question... what if I wanted to seed it initially with some information, then wanted to subsequently add records in the future? There doesn't seem to be a good programmatic way of doing this, and I've seen warning against doing so using migration code.

Heroku offers manual means of managing a database, be it removing or adding new records, but this intervention, I think, should be an absolute last resort.

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but I'm pretty bad at searching this particular inquiry.

Comment: you got the `seed.rb` purpose correctly, but i guess you can use the `first_or_create`/`find_or_create_by` methods, so the data the you already used in the `seed` file won't be seeded again after you update that file. (and again, as you said already: `seed.rb` is mean for Bootstrapping Data. so it won't be a good practice to update it and use it over and over... i just gave you and idea of how you might achieve it :P )

Comment: and some other way i can think of is making a custom rake task. you cant find an example in [**this link**](https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-simple-rake-task). so for every update you want to me, you can create a new task so add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve this problem by having a directory of `db/data` and migrations run that will load the latest file from the data directory and load it into the db.

eg we do this for keeping our set of postal codes up to date. Whenever we identify a missing postcode, we add it to the `db/data/postcodes.yaml` file then create a migration that runs the rake-task that loads the postcodes from the file.

The data directory is in git, so you can see the data-changes over time, and the current `db/data/postcodes.yaml` is always the most up-to-date version.

The rake task, in this case, reads through the file and does a `find_or_create_by` the postcode (updating if we find an existing one).